# How to add a image or thumbnail to email sender on Rails Mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I want to set a logo for the LCA Systems mail that I am sending from my application to be as the others bellow. Now it is showing just an Interrogation point. Is there any way to replace this interrogation to an image?

[image: My inbox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a Google+ profile using your sending email address. If that address is `noreply@lcasystems.com`, simply create a Google+ account using that address.

- https://accounts.google.com

Other email clients will use Gravatar. Sign up for an account using the email address you use to send messages.

- https://gravatar.com

There is no universal method to get all email clients to use one central avatar for personalization.

Good luck.

Comment: So I created the Gravatar Avatar, but this G+ account is not a default account... It seems that the regular account just accepts @gmail emails.

Comment: I used a web browser that I never use for Google and found a better address. If you use `https://accounts.google.com`, click `sign in`, then `create new account` set up an account, you can click `Use my current email address instead` and not use an `@gmail.com` address. Doing gets my avatar to show up in Gmail. I updated my response.

Comment: @LuizHenrique If you did the same thing with Gravatar, it will work on a variety of other email clients. I just don't have a list handy.